# Check if parent class exists in jQuery and set different var

Tags: javascript, jquery

A website has category descriptions. This descriptions are to long and I made them shorter with jQuery. 
The wordcount max default value is 7 words

```
var maxWords = 7;
```

When the parent css class **expanded** exists

```
 <div class="below expanded">
```

the var maxWords has to be 20;

```
var maxWords = 20;
```

To realise this, I added in my jQuery function this:

```
if($(this).closest(".below").hasClass(".expanded")) {
{
var maxWords = 7;
} else {
var maxWords = 20;
}
```

But this did not work.

I made a JSFiddle for you to see the full jQuery Code. The category2 description needs 20 words instead of 7.

To JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1pehcux5/

Thank you very much.

Comment: should be without point of class: `.hasClass("expanded")`

Comment: U mean just: if($(this).closest("expanded")) { ? I tried this already but when this is in, the text is not short anymore. You can try in the jsfiddle.

Comment: i mean `.hasClass(".expanded")` should be `.hasClass("expanded")`

Comment: simply remove `.` dot from `hasClass(".expanded"))`

Comment: I tried it, but the descriptions are not short anymore. Please try it in the fiddle.

Comment: The fiddle seems to be working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just modify code like this:-

```
var maxWords = 20;
//check with ! and remove . from expanded
if(!$(this).closest(".below").hasClass("expanded")) {
    maxWords = 7;
}
```

Working snippet:- https://jsfiddle.net/65cje83w/

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is working like a charm.

Comment: @LarsVegas glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to remove the dot `(.)` from  `.hasClass(".expanded")` so it looks like `.hasClass("expanded")`

Second, you have a `{` to many in `"expanded")) {{ maxWords`;

Third, remove the `var` from `maxWords = 7` and `maxWords = 20` since you don't need to declare it.

```
if ($(this).closest(".below").hasClass("expanded")) {
  maxWords = 7;
} else {
  maxWords = 20;
}
```

**Working demo**

```js
$('.descshort').each(function() {
  var words = $(this).text().replace(".", ". ").replace(",", ", ").split(" ").filter(function(a) {
    return a.trim()
  });


  var maxWords = 7;
  if ($(this).closest(".below").hasClass("expanded")) {
    maxWords = 7;
  } else {
    maxWords = 20;
  }

  var arr = [];
  var index = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < words.length && arr.length + 1 <= maxWords; i++) {
    if (words[i] != ',' && words[i] != '.') {
      arr.push(words[i]);
    }
    index = i + 1;
  }
  if (arr.length == maxWords && words.length > maxWords) {

    html = '<span>' + words.slice(0, index).join(" ") + '</span>' + '<span class="more_text" style="display:none;"> ' + words.slice(index, words.length).join(" ") + '</span>' + '<span style="display:inline-block" id="dots">...</span> <a href="#" class="read_more">+</a>'

    $(this).html(html)

    $(this).find('a.read_more').click(function(event) {
      $(this).toggleClass("less");
      event.preventDefault();

      if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).html("<u>[ close ]</u>")
        $(this).parent().find(".more_text").show();
      } else {
        $(this).html("+")
        $(this).parent().find(".more_text").hide();

      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="below">
  <div class="forumslist">
    <p class="header">Section</p>
    <div class="forum-left">
      <h3>Category</h3>
      <p class="description descshort">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="below expanded">
  <div class="forumslist">
    <p class="header">Section2</p>
    <div class="forum-left">
      <h3>Category 2</h3>
      <p class="description descshort">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I may add, the if/else needs to have `maxWords = 20;` first and `maxWords = 7;` second

Comment: Yes, this seems to work but like Adder said, first need 20 and second 7. Weired.

Answer (score 0):

The if/else is not properly writen. You need to change it to this:

```
var maxWords = 7;

if( $(this).closest(".below").hasClass("expanded") ) {
    maxWords = 20;
} else {
    maxWords = 7;
}
```

You were also redeclaring the var maxWords inside of each scope in the if/else, not overwritting the global variable.

Comment: Then the first "if" is failing. You should set it on a click for example, you have to trigger it somehow.